# Image Hover Overlay -- Need Colorful Transparency

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a colorful transparent overlay when you hover over an image (any color: purple, blue, red, orange would be great), but instead I am getting a white transparent overlay. Please note, I am using bootstrap grid so that my images stay responsive. I've tried everything I can think of... adding a background-color: blue with some opacity, but I am stuck. White overlay looks okay, but I wanted to have some fun with the color. Please see my code below and tell me what I need to do. Many thanks!

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="hover12 col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                     <img src="images/flowers4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>
             <div class="hover12 col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                     <img src="images/flowers5.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>
     </div> <!-- closes div row -->
</div> <!-- closes div container -->
```

CSS code:

```
.hover12 img {
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.hover12 img:hover{
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `rgba()` for `background-color`? For example: `background-color : rgba(22,110,77,0.5);`

Answer (score 0):

`opacity` fades out the entire element including its background, it does not make  the contents transparent and the background show through. What you would want to do instead is either put an element with your color (blue perhaps) underneath the image and make the image opaque (with `opacity`), or hide and show an element on top of the image that has some transparency.

Here is an example. On hover, the image becomes 50% opaque and you can see the blue element under it showing through.

```css
.img-container {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.img-container img:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQU-rOCZDSdyIGgSvZhU-lqIhG32Yd8KrwI3gWKXSCayFXQuJTx0g" /></div>
```

---

Edit:

I just looked at your code again and realized you basically have it right, except you have the background color set on the `img` element, but it should be set on the element that contains the img, which is the `.thumbnail` class, so try just adding:

```
.thumbnail {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: oh wow! That actually worked. It's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much for looking at my code and helping me with this. I appreciate it!

Comment: @RadhikaSuvorova Glad I could help. Please remember to up-vote or mark answers as accepted when they are helpful. Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: if I didn't have class thumbnail in my code, to which element would I add the color background-color: blue to achieve that effect?

Comment: The element that contains the `img` element, so in this case the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best accomplished using a pseudoelement that overlays the image. Here is how to create a pseudoelement that overlays an image and has reduced opacity when the image is rolled over:

```css
#theimg {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#theimg::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
}


#theimg:hover::after {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div id="theimg">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LDR6AWn.png?1" />
</div>
```

Comment: This worked also! It looked a bit funky going over the bootstrap grid images, but after adjusting the percentages from 100% original size to 91% for the width and 95% for the height, it looked pretty good. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @RadhikaSuvorova Glad it helped! Please don't forget to mark whichever answer you ended up using as accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use `:before` to make a semi-transparent overlay:

```
img:hover:before {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
}
```

Downside is that it will block the image being clickable, and may be an issue when you are using images with CSS `background` instead of the `<img />` in HTML.

---

Another way, if Internet Explorer support isn't an issue (which could be the case if this effect is just for show), you could play around with the CSS `filter`. It's not as easy as overlaying a transparent image over the image, but you can get some very nice effects:

```
img.grayscale:hover { -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%); }
img.contrast:hover { -webkit-filter: contrast(150%); filter: contrast(150%); }
img.brightness:hover { -webkit-filter: brightness(1.5); filter: brightness(1.5); }
img.hue-rotate:hover { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg); filter: hue-rotate(90deg); }
img.saturate:hover { -webkit-filter: saturate(2); filter: saturate(2); }
img.blur:hover { -webkit-filter: blur(2px); filter: blur(2px); }
img.invert:hover { -webkit-filter: invert(1); filter: invert(1); }
img.sepia:hover { -webkit-filter: sepia(75%); filter: sepia(75%); }
```

For your question, I would recommend using `.hue-rotate` and maybe add a CSS `transition`. Note: you can combine effects!

Play around with sliders:
http://www.cssreflex.com/css-generators/filter/ or http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html